# How to support MOV(quick time) in android?

Tags: android, media-player, mov

I want to play in .mov file in android. But videoview or mediaplayer doesn't support this meida format. How can i add the support to it?

Answer (score 8):

In general Android doesn't support any other media formats than the one [listed here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). That being said, there are quite a few 3rd party players that enable playback of more exotic formats, most of which are probably based around ffmpeg. You might want to take a look at the [open source Dolpin Player](http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/) (actual player also available in the [Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.broov.player)) for Android for some more pointers - not sure if mov playback is supported by default though.

However, since most mov files are actually H.264 encoded these days, why not remultiplex (or re-encode, depending on the source) into an something that Android plays nice with, e.g. an mp4 container? In terms of video support on Android, H.264 is definitely the way, as also pointed out by the 'Video Encoding Recommendations' section in the earlier link.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to play it anyway. The Quicktime .mov specification is the predecessor of the MP4 spec. There are only differences in a few atoms/boxes. You will be able to play an MP4 as .mov and a .mov as MP4 in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I found that even the big named players such as MX Player, BS Player and VLC for Android would not play .mov files correctly, especially those that had been recoreded on my wifes iphone 4s.
The playback was very choppy on my Nexus 7 and Nexus 10 and totally unwatchable on my HTC One (M7). 
The player I found and installed that will play old and new iphone movie clips (.mov) flawlessly was found freely available from the Google Play Store.
Here is the best player I have found and believe me I have tried lots:
[Playing .MOV files on an Android Device](http://www.4u3.biz/Articles/computers/operating-systems/android/playing-.mov-files-on-an-android-device.html) 
Hope this helps some of those people with an Android device wishing to view iphone .mov files.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but times changin'
Now we can use the ExoPlayer as a custom Video Player (like VideoView), it supports more formats than the VideoView on android.

It's really simple to use, just to play videos, but has the powerfull of customization if you needed.

https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/

Give it a try and please respond if this helped you.