# Android Streaming video MOV with ACC (mp4a) audio and H264 video

Tags: android, video, audio-streaming, mov, acc

I would like to show some video in my android application.
Video are like: `http://myserver.com/video/myvideo.mov` All the video are in **.mov** and some in **.flv**.

**.mov** have `H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (avc1)` video channel, and `MPEG ACC Audio (mp4a)` audio channel.

**.flv** have `Flash Video (flv1)` video channel, and  `MPEG Audio layer 1/2/3 (mpga)` audio channel.

If I play the **.mov** with the default android player I can see the video image, but I can't hear anithing.
With the **.flv** I can see and hear the file in the default android player.

Is there a way to play correctly the **.mov** with the `MPEG ACC Audio (mp4a)` audio channel?
Anyone know if there is a custom library to play this .mov files? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) MOV container even with H264/AAC inside is not supported in Android. The underlying reason is that MOV (aka quicktime file format) is a proprietary container from Apple (it is a close one from MP4 but still not the same) - most of the time it works 100% only on Apple device and/or quicktime player.

FLV container from Adobe is also not supported in Android (FLV can be packed with H263 or H264 video inside).

It can work on some device but as you experienced it, it can be clunky and surely inconsistent across devices.

Your best bet is to package/transcode your file in a format where you know you will have cross-Android compatibility.

If you want it badly you could think about building your own video player/decoder to play back mov/flv files (like with ffmpeg) but it is an advanced project in itself and providing code for that would be outside of the scope of stackoverflow - maybe have a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/).

Comment: Hello Florestan06, thank you for your reply. Now I understood about .mov incompatibility. I use same file in desktop and apple ios application so there is a problem! If I use a flv video format (`Flash Video (flv1)` for video + `MPEG Audio layer 1/2/3 (mpga)` for audio) it will works on most of android device? Do you know if there are some open source library that could help me? Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can try http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/ for a start. It has been mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600229/how-to-support-movquick-time-in-android

Comment: FLV will not work well on all Android devices. It can work here and there but with no guarantee of support.